# urllib.request.Request use Python code for scrape data from Twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to SCRAPE DATA FROM TWITTER. previously working code does not work any more the twitter is sending weard html commends. i am using different  urllib.request.Request    commands stil not getting the html structure as i seen it in browers. i could not find a solution to my problem

alternative 1

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'https://twitter.com/search?l=&q=%22gsm%22%20since%3A2017-01-01%20until%3A2017-05-02&src=typd'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name': 'Michael Foord',
          'location': 'Northampton',
          'language': 'Python' }
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
```

alternative 2:

```
headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
```

is there any way that  i could solve this issue with urllib or any other way

Comment: Exactly what does not work?

Comment: I hope you have a good reason for not using Twitter's API instead of scraping.